# C# .NET ASP MVC Entity Framework, наполнение базы

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, миграция, entity

Занимаюсь по курсу https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftDumxp8K7k
Возникла следующая проблема в коде: наполнение не отображается в базе. Т.е. делая точку останова на строках 12, 16 и 21. Запуская приложение изменения в базе не происходят.

Наполнение для таблиц Migration:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DataLayer
{
    public static class SampleData
    {
        public static void InitData(EFDBContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Directory.Any())
            {
                context.Directory.Add(new Entityes.Directory() { Title = "First Directory", Html = "<b>Directory Content</b>" });
                context.Directory.Add(new Entityes.Directory() { Title = "Second Directory", Html = "<b>Directory Content</b>" });
                context.SaveChanges();

                context.Material.Add(new Entityes.Material() { Title = "First Material", Html = "<i>Material Content</i>", DirectoryId = context.Directory.First().Id });
                context.Material.Add(new Entityes.Material() { Title = "Second Material", Html = "<i>Material Content</i>", DirectoryId = context.Directory.First().Id });
                context.Material.Add(new Entityes.Material() { Title = "Third Material", Html = "<i>Material Content</i>", DirectoryId = context.Directory.Last().Id });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Material

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DataLayer.Entityes
{
    public class Material : Page
    {
        public int DirectoryId { get; set; } //Внешний ключ
        public Directory Directory { get; set; } //Навигационное свойство
    }
}
```

Directory

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DataLayer.Entityes
{
    public class Directory : Page
    {
        public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Сам я — новичок в программировании от слова «дуб», знаю немного основ, но уже стараюсь создать небольшой проект. Буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: Лажовый урок. Тестовые данные добавлять следует в классе контекста в методе `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

Comment: пример как это делать [здесь](https://youtu.be/X__Yd6IOfVg?list=PLUTrDHuvZc4EDn8K9czBDuaZ7bQfeQ-Am&t=1201)

Comment: Ну если ваш код прошелся по точкам остановки и не выдал ошибок, то скорее всего данные появились в базе. Вопрос только в какой базе данных и в правильную ли базу вы смотрите. Ведь EF вполне может создать рядом новую и наполнить её, если вы ошиблись где-то или были невнимательны.

Comment: Подскажите, в каких строках Вы ставите точки останова, честно говоря, считать самому по номерам желания нет. Плюс позволю себе указать Вам на ошибку: Entities, а не Entityes.Затем, есть вопрос: что такое Page? И просьба: покажите, пожалуйста Ваш DbContext и то, как Вы его создаёте.